# Could a graphics card port fault result in brightness/contrast differences?

Tags: multiple-monitors, graphics-card, vga, dvi

I'll try explain this as best I can, I'm fairly stumped as to how this issue could be caused.

I have an XFX Radeon 5850 that has four outputs. Two of these are DVI, one is HDMI, one is display port. I'm currently using a dual monitor setup, connecting both DVI outputs to identical monitors through a DVI->Analogue converter (the monitor inputs are VGA).

The problem is, the image on one monitor is noticeably more "colourful" than the other monitor. For example, the whites are much brighter and everything in general just looks more "vibrant". The effect here is that it makes the image on the other monitor look quite dull.

My first thought was monitor issue, but after investigating, it honestly seems like the graphics card is somehow at fault here. If I have monitor 1 connected to port 1 (and therefore monitor 2 in port 2), then monitor 1 is the "vibrant" monitor. If I connect monitor 2  to port 1 (and therefore monitor 1 to port 2), then monitor 2 is the more vibrant one. In essence, no matter which combination of plugging things in I try, the device connected to port 1 is always much more vibrant than the device connected to port 2.

Since the monitors seemed fine, the next thought was a software issue. Instead of messing with the Windows settings/CCC panel, I booted up a linux live CD where I managed to get the same result. After stretching a white image across both screens, the screen connected to port 1 is much brighter.

Is it possible in any way that one port of the graphics card is giving a corrupt output signal of some kind, or am I missing something completely trivial? I'm honestly stumped as to what the issue could be here. If I've explained something poorly then please say so and I'll do my best to explain further, it's a very odd issue.

Edit: I forgot to make clear that I have tried different DVI->Analogue converters, VGA cables etc, only to receive the same problem.

Answer (score 1):

You have done all the proper testing anyone would ask you to do.  You swapped monitors, booted off a Linux LivdCD, etc.  The only thing I would ask, as it wasnt clear in your explanation, is did you try swapping the video cables to see if they were the issue?  If not, leave the monitors as is and swap the video cables and see if they make a difference.

If the cables are not the issue, then it definitely sounds like a hardware issue.  The best thing to do at this point would be to contact ATI support and talk to them.  This may be a hardware defect.

Answer (score 1):

I agree with Keltari, you have done all of the standard diagnostics steps except for testing the cables.

In addition to the suggestion to contact ATI about a possible RMA, you could also try a couple of more diagnostic steps:

- Check the [ICC color profiles](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ICC_profile) set for the monitors. They [control all aspects](http://www.tftcentral.co.uk/articles/icc_profiles.htm) of color, brightness, contrast, etc.
- [Check](http://www.nirsoft.net/utils/monitor_info_view.html) the [EDID](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Extended_display_identification_data) (especially the [raw data](http://www.eldim.fr/products/display-controller/fpdlite/fpdlite-free-tools)) on both monitors.

While the monitors may be identical makes and models, they may also be from different lots and have different data which can cause them to be seen as slightly different. Of course if that were the case, then the difference *should* make the color difference carry over with the monitor to the other port, but unfortunately, they could end up getting stuck because they are too similar.

The problem is that if you still had one monitor brighter when booting into a Linux PE, then it is almost certainly not a setting or configuration issue.

The only thing left to check other than the cables is the adapters. It could be that one has a bad resistor or something. Check what happens if you switch the cables, what happens if you switch the adapters, and what happens if you switch the cables *and* adapters (that’s four different combinations; eight if you count switching the monitors).

Comment: Sorry, I should have made it clear that I've tried different adapters as well. 
The monitors do have HDMI/DVI input in addition to VGA, would it be worth purchasing the appropriate leads so that all graphics card output is digital? I suppose this would give me a baseline as to what the images coming out of the card should look like.

Comment: I’m confused, the card and monitors have DVI ports and you have a DVI cable, but you used an adapter to connect through the VGA port? Maybe you should use a graphics program (even MSPaint would do) to draw a schematic and add it to the question to clarify.

Comment: The monitors have DVI, VGA and HDMI inputs. The only cables I have are VGA cables, hence I'm using DVI->Analogue converters connected to the graphics card's DVI outputs. The converters were left over from a previous setup, I figured I'd use them instead of purchasing new cables since I didn't think it would make too much of a difference. Hope that clarifies things a bit.

Edit: I've ordered some more cables so that I can scrap the analogue converters, though it shouldn't really make a difference, should it?

Comment: Ah, okay. So it’s card:DVI→DVI-VGA-adapter→VGA:monitor. Hmm, the analog conversion can certainly play a role in creating some problems, but if you have tried every combination of port-adapter-cable-monitor already, then it seems likely that the card is actually outputting different data to the two ports. Here’s another (surprisingly difficult) diagnostic question: which port is “bad”? That is, is one too bright or too dim? (Of course this would require somehow determine a baseline to figure out what they *should* be looking like, which may be difficult).

Comment: Hah, exactly my thought! The more vibrant port could well be the faulty one, with the dimmer looking one being the intended image output (or vice versa). I've ordered cables such that I can try the HDMI and DisplayPort outputs on my card (HDMI->HDMI, DisplayPort->HDMI), as well as two DVI->DVI cables so I can do away with analogue signals completely. Hopefully using the HDMI/DisplayPort outputs will give me a baseline.

I've fired a support ticket off to XFX in the meantime, though I don't expect they'll do anything about it (I've had the card since 2009, it's had a good life).

Comment: Ah, okay; so no RMA for you! `:-)` Yes, hopefully the digital cables will help (though it’s not a guarantee; I switched my VGA cable with a DVI cable and I still—or perhaps *now*?—get weird flickering dotted tearing across the screen whenever it comes out of standby until I reset the screen). Anyway, worst case scenario, you never really find out exactly what happened (welcome to the world of computers), but you can probably adjust one or the other with in-monitor and/or in-software controls to make them both look to your liking.

Answer (score 0):

> DVI->Analogue converter (the monitor inputs are VGA)

I'd try a different DVI->Analogue converter before swapping the graphics card.

Comment: My apologies, I should have been clear on that. I've already tried different analogue converters and received the same issue.